# Facebook not scraping the url on doing manual request still returns status 200 OK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

I'm sending a request on graph endpoint to manually clear the `facebook graph` cache for the URL, whenever the page's sharable content (image specially) is changed, using:

```
POST: https://graph.facebook.com?id=http://www.merainstitute.com/vibrant&scrape=true  
(Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update)
```

Adround 10-12 days ago it was working perfect. Whenever I changed the image and ran this url `facebook` cleared its cache and would show the latest image.

But now its **not working**. I've changed nothing in my code, I've checked the `og` meta properties, checked the `og:image` url that its accessible and is pointing to latest image, everything is same and according to specification.

You can also check the meta tags on the embedded URL maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well it was a bug in facebook platform API and was already reported as:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1565027973760906/

And the best part is they have fixed it.